# Converting Javascript Ajax code to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need converting this code to jQuery.

Thank you very much.

```
  function myItem(id,  page) {  
        AjaxPost(WEB_URL+'/myitems.inc.php', "page="+page+"&id="+id, 
            function () {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
                    div('myItem_box').innerHTML += xmlHttp.responseText;
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: What did *you* try so far?

Comment: What's preventing you? jQuery is well documented.

Comment: Always use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to properly encode query string parameters. And can `xmlHttp.readyState` contain `"complete"`?

Comment: didn't know this was **`stackConvertMyCode.com`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myItem(id, page) {
    $.post({
        url: WEB_URL + '/myitems.inc.php',
        data: {page: page, id: id},
        success: function(response) {
            $('#myItem_box').append(response);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: `$('#myItem_box').html($('#myItem_box').html()+response);` Please fix that. It's really awful.

Comment: @BlueSkies I changed to the form of `.html()` that uses a function to modify the old value, that better?

Comment: Marginally. The main offense is that you're destroying that part of the DOM only to rebuild it with the new content. This will destroy any handlers and other data associated with those old elements. I know OP is doing the same thing, but it needs to be corrected. Use `.append()` instead.

Comment: There's a 90% probability, IMO, that it's just a text field.

Comment: Could be. If so, you can use `.text()` with a function argument as well. The important thing is that this is clearly a complete beginner, so enforcing practices like this isn't a great idea. Using `.append()` will work whether or not it's HTML. If it's a form field, then it should be `.val()`.

Comment: To do that right, I'd really need to see the structure of the DIV that he's adding to, and the type of response (is it text or HTML, do I need to wrap it in a DIV or SPAN before calling `.append()`?)

Comment: Why would you need to wrap it? `$("#myItem_box").append(response);` jQuery handles the creation of the new content.

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly thought it would try to detect whether the string is an HTML string or a selector.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, they don't accept a selector string in that method.